# Why do I get a valid but inaccurate $nearSphere query when using the typed methods of the C# driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb, geospatial, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to perform a `$nearSphere` query against my collection of documents in MongoDB. Before learning about the specific methods to call to generate the query in a typed way, I used the following string interpolation to create my query myself, following the documentation online:

```
var query = _col.Find($"{{ location: {{ $nearSphere: {{ $geometry: {{ type: \"Point\", coordinates: [ {lon}, {lat} ] }}, $maxDistance: {rad} }} }} }}");
```

This worked fine. My query was accurate. But wherever possible, I'd like to use the typed methods instead so the compiler can help me in the future, so I looked online to figure out how to code it, and I came up with this after reading a previous StackOverflow answer:

```
var filter = Builders<Node>.Filter.NearSphere(n => n.Location, lon, lat, rad);
var query2 = _col.Find<Node>(filter);
```

The problem is that these generate different queries under the hood, and the query generated by the latter is inaccurate. It catches many more points.

By calling `.ToString()` on the queries generated, I see that the first one turns into...

```
{find({ "location" : { "$nearSphere" : { "$geometry" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [1, 2] }, "$maxDistance" : 3 } } })}
```

...which produces an accurate result).

And the second one turns into...

```
{find({ "location" : { "$nearSphere" : [1.0, 2.0], "$maxDistance" : 3.0 } })}
```

...which has a different form and does not produce an accurate result.

Note that the numbers used for longitude, latitude, and radius here are examples, my app used realistic values for my local area where I could confirm by checking OpenStreetMap data.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this myself by spending a lot more time in the documentation and playing with code until it compiled. I found it hard to find the solution to this in the documentation, since they have no examples of performing geospatial queries aside from a small section about not supporting geospatial queries vs LINQ right now.

The code for performing this type of query with version `2.7` of the C# driver is:

```
var filterPoint = GeoJson.Point(new GeoJson2DCoordinates(lon, lat));

var filter = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<Node>()
             .NearSphere(n => n.Location, filterPoint, rad);

var query = _col.Find<Node>(filter);
```

I also had to make sure I was using the MongoDB GeoJSON point data type in my model (the class I use to perform the queries):

```
public class Node
{
    [BsonElement("_id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("location")]
    public GeoJsonPoint<GeoJson2DCoordinates> Location { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("tags")]
    public BsonDocument Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Note that the `Tags` property represents any JSON type, so I use `BsonDocument`. I can map it to a `Dictionary<string, object` later when returning the response.

And just to provide a more complete example for anyone reading this, this is the code I used after preparing the query to run it, map the results to my DTO, and send the 200 response in ASP.NET Core 2.1:

```
// Perform query and map to DTO
var res = (await query.ToListAsync()).Select(n =>
{
    var lonLat = n.Location.Coordinates.Values.ToArray();

    return new NodeBase
    {
        Id = n.Id.ToString(),
        Location = new SimpleGeoJsonPoint
        {
            Lon = lonLat[0],
            Lat = lonLat[1],
        },
        Tags = n.Tags.ToDictionary(),
    };
});

return Ok(new MultiSearchResult<NodeBase>
{
    Count = res.Count(),
    Results = res,
});
```

Note that `NodeBase` is my DTO for returning my `Node` documents to the client when they perform the search. `SimpleGeoJsonPoint` is my DTO used in other DTOs for representing the GeoJSON point in a simple way. I didn't need the fluff, just the longitude and latitude. `MultiSearchResult<T>` is my generic DTO for returning search results to the client.